# An api to get actual time for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, timezone

My server clock is running slow for some reason. I need to put a timestamp on my database transactions and need a reliable time source. Is there an api to the world time zone site or something similar?

Comment: how can a server clock run slow? have you checked the BIOS cell ?

Comment: its a relatively older machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you can get the server to [automatically synchronize with a known time server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773061(WS.10).aspx), right ?  Might be easier than coding something custom.

If you want to implement it yourself, you will need to implement a client of the Simple Network Time Protocol (or find an open source one). There are plenty of [SNTP servers available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262680), and the SNTP should be relatively easy to implement. [Here is the RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2030.html).

Comment: I did not know that I could sync the server time. Thanks for providing both options.